# How do I transfer over the data and format it the way I want?

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets on my Excel: Worksheet (No data but have proper headings) and Report 1 (Consists of the original data and headings)

Right now I want to transfer the data from Report 1 to Worksheet but when I transfer over, I need the data from Report 1 column M, N and O to be transferred to column B in Worksheet. The data in column M, N and O should be separated with a '-'.

All this should be done with Excel Macros but I do not know how.

Comment: You don't need macros, a simple CONCATENATE formula will do the job you need it to.  Also, while we are happy to help you out, we kinda expect you've had a try at solving the problem yourself and can demonstrate what you've done so we know where to help.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! However, my supervisor expects me to use Macro to run this series of actions as there are other data to be transferred over. Plus I would really love to experiment out the codes but this was delegated to me last minute and I need it urgently by tomorrow. @Dave

Comment: If you don't know how to write/use a macro, you will either have to learn that, or hire someone.  You could start by trying to record a macro; then look here and elsewhere for how to clean it up.  This is not a free code-writing service. Please read the HELP pages for information as to [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to Provide an Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yeah I recorded the macro and I cleaned it up myself already. Thanks for "trying" to help. @RonRosenfeld

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have solved this problem after some tips were given.

Apparently, I just recorded the Macro and used the CONCATENATE formula, putting a "-" in between and " " for spacing.